# Can't focus on input Text in react native Android TV

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-tv

I am working on a React Native app and I have the following code that renders a Text Input and a button which submits a request to my API. With my Android TV emulator, I can type input into the text field by first selecting the text input with my mouse and then typing on my keyboard. but I can't able to use D-pad of emulator for focus and select the input field for type anything plz help.

```
      <View style={{flexDirection:'column',alignItems:'center'}}>
          { !isEnabled ?
            <TouchableHighlight
           
            style={[
              styles.input,
              textInputFocused && styles.textInputContainerFocused,
            ]}>
           <TextInput
              ref={InputTextRef}
              onFocus={() => {
                setTextInputFocused(true);
              }}
              onBlur={() => {
                setTextInputFocused(false);
              }}
             // style={styles.input}
              onChangeText={setUrls}
              value={urls}
              placeholder="Enter Your URL"
              placeholderTextColor="#f4f3f4"
              color= '#f4f3f4'
              style={styles.textInput}
            />
            </TouchableHighlight>
             : 
              <>
              <TextInput
              ref={InputTextRef}
              onFocus={()=>InputTextRef.current.focus()}
              style={styles.input}
              onChangeText={setUrls}
              value={urls}
              placeholder="Enter Your URL"
              placeholderTextColor="#f4f3f4"
              color= '#f4f3f4'
              />
              <TextInput
              ref={InputTextRef}
              onFocus={()=>InputTextRef.current.focus()}
              style={styles.input}
              onChangeText={setKeys}
              value={keys}
              placeholder="Enter Your Account Id"
              placeholderTextColor="#f4f3f4"
              color= '#f4f3f4'
            />
            </>
            }  
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
      <View >
        <Toggle/>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.search}  onPress= {handleSearchButton}>
            <Text style={[styles.watchtext]}>Submit</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      </View>
      </View>
    <Footer/>
  </View>
 );
```

}

Comment: Did you ever manage to get a fix for this? I am experiencing the same issue on AndroidTV devices

Comment: its was fix after some time adding different ref for different TextInput.